# how to clear the client cache whe delete a image on laravel?

Tags: php, view, browser-cache, laravel-5.6

Laravel 5.6 ubuntu 16.04

the view

```
<div class="col-10">
   <img  src="{{$img_del}}"     class="rounded  mx-auto d-block img-fluidc" alt="testimage">
</div>
```

when I delete the image on controller use

```
$path=public_path().$img_del;

Storage::delete($img_del);
or
unlink($path);
```

when the client reload the page it got the cache image.
so it shows the same page having the del image,
How can I clear the client cache of this image?
Or just tell the client brower to reload from the server not from the cache?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to effectively clear client browser cache.
In this particular case you can reload the page (redirect back to page) with a get parameter of current timestamp. example url?t=234234234234

In your view you can append this parameter to end of src attribute of img `<img src="fafasdf.jpg?t=234234234234" />` forcing a reload of image.

But, showing a non existing image is not preferred as browsers may behave oddly (like image 404 icon). Why don't you keep the image paths is database and create your view from database rows. This will enable you to show the latest set of images to the user as you will delete image from database as well when you unlink it.